# How do I allow users to delete their post from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I have a Recycle view set up that it's populated with user's post from Firebase. I would like to implement a feature that allows user's to remove their own post(Similar to Facebook or Instagram). So far I have written some code that allows a post to be removed, but any user have access to remove it.

```
//This is how my database is set up 
 Post
 -LlISwmjd0pBXzkNHJGW (random push id)
 desc: "Used textbook"
 id:   "Zk32WqxcCHbR1op6j9inFudFJF23"
 image: "image link"
 name:    "user name"
 profileimage: "profile image"




//This method allows a post to be removed
  //Creates popup and allows user to delete from RecycleView
    public void openOptionMenu(View v, final int position) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu1:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edit clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.menu2:
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post").child(randomPostKeyId).removeValue();
                        postList.remove(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        //default intent
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }
```

Comment: You can store the firebase id of the user along with other post details and compare if current user id on the device is same as user id of the post. If they are same, then allow deletion else do not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Firebase Security rules so that only the owner can modify/delete the post.
Let's say every post has an attribute that contains User Id of the user who created it, if the name of key was **`ownerId`** then it would look like this:

```
{
// Allow anyone to read data, but only authenticated content owners can
// make changes to their data

  "rules": {
    "Post": {
      "${postId}": {
        ".read": true,
        // or ".read": "auth.uid != null" for only authenticated users
        ".write": "root.child('Post').child(postId).child('ownerId').val() == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules for complete ddocumentation.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!  --  ".write": "root.child('posts').child($postId).child('userId').val() == auth.uid"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understood your problem correctly. As per my understanding, you want show the delete option for a post if that post is created by the user interacting.

If thats the case, then add a check in the "openOptionMenu" method to see whether the post.name==currentUser.name. If yes, continue with what ever you are doing right now. Else inflate a new options menu with delete option not present.

Comment: That may result in security problems, this should be validated on server side not on client side.

Comment: Server side obviously should validate this, but in client side also, we need to have this check. Otherwise there is no point in showing a delete button and nothing happens when user clicks on it (if it has server validation).